# Mac Mini fan gone furious

Tags: mac-mini

something awful happened to my mini.
I placed it under my aircon, and for some reason, the aircon started to drip.
right on the fan grills on the mini.
not a lot, probably like an eighth of a glass of water.
so, i rushed to unplug everything from the mini.
and leave it to dry.
problem is... when i plug it all in, i start with the power cable.
just when i plug it, the fan gone furious. like 6000rpm furious.
the state of the mini is currently OFF.
that's one thing i'm confused about.
second, after a while the fan speed goes down..
but never really really low.
even when it's off, and the room is cold (not just cool) it's still noticeably whirring.
and the mini is still OFF.
when i turn it on.. after just 15-20 minutes the fan goes furious again.
like 6000rpm.
what can i do to fix this, and how much damage have i done.
and to answer a few preliminary questions.
the mini is a late 2009 mini, C2D, 4GB ram, and usually running on 18C room.
and i've never upgraded any hardware, RAM, HDD, everything.. still as it was.

Comment: How long did you let it dry?  It can take days, even when put in a sealed bag with dry rice.

Comment: i dried it with a hair dryer for an hour. not with hot blower, just air blower.

Answer (score 3):

Since it got wet, I'm inclined to believe this is hardware damage.

I recommend that you give it another few days to dry, without use. Keep it completely unplugged for this time.

If that doesn't work, run [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509). If it finds problems, take it to the Apple Store for service.

Good luck.

Comment: the system works fine though.. the os is running fine, just the fan is driving me nuts. so i was wondering about the extent of damage to the machine.

Comment: You can make any water damage worse by turning the machine on.  Unplug it and wait for several days.

Answer (score 3):

**After** you've waited for it to dry as Nathan said, if the problem persists you can try to [reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964), as it's a common solution for fans not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the older, taller Mini or the newer shorter one? Also, did you take it apart at all while you were drying it?

If the answer to both of these questions is "Yes," then you may have unplugged the fan control cable. Unplugging this cable makes the fan run constantly. You will need to open the case back up and make sure that the little, tiny cable on the front of the logic board is properly plugged in.